# Toad for oracle hangs on this query: select sql_text from V$sqltext_with_newlines where address = (select DECODE

Tags: oracle, toad

What is it for?

```
select sql_text
from V$sqltext_with_newlines where
address = (select DECODE(RAWTOHEX(sql_address), '00', prev_sql_addr, sql_address
)
 from   V$session
 where username = :uname
 and sid = :snum)
ORDER BY piece
```

I just know it's generated by toad and hungs up a very powerful production environment

Some table sessione showed this:

```
COUNT(0) EVENT
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 smon timer
         1 db file parallel read
         1 pmon timer
         1 read by other session
         1 SQL*Net message to client
         1 PL/SQL lock timer
         2 SQL*Net break/reset to client
         2 PX Deq Credit: send blkd
         7 db file scattered read
         8 db file sequential read
        12 jobq slave wait
        14 PX Deq: Execution Msg
        30 rdbms ipc message
       333 SQL*Net message from client
       450 latch: library cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a very simple query, I'd be surprised if it's really causing problems.  Data dictionary views often use dozens of tables, but the execution plan for this query only has 9 steps on my system and the query runs very quickly.  Even if the optimizer got the plan totally wrong the tables involved aren't very large so things shouldn't run too horribly slow.

Is the query really doing something, or just sitting there waiting for someone to retrieve more rows?  Try using something like this to find out the resources it's consuming.  Run it a couple of times, if the numbers don't increase the query is not a problem:

```
select elapsed_time/1000000 elapsed_seconds, cpu_time/1000000 cpu_seconds
    ,user_io_wait_time/1000000 user_io_wait_seconds, buffer_gets
    ,executions, v$sql.*
from v$sql
where lower(sql_text) like lower('%DECODE(RAWTOHEX(sql_address)%');
```

Your query seems to retrieve the currently running statement, although I'm not sure exactly what TOAD uses it for.  Maybe it's part of the session browser or something?  TOAD and all similar query tools run many queries like this in the background.  I've never seen them bring down a server.  Although with TOAD it's very possible that there's some bug that causes the UI to freeze and make it appear to be working really hard on a query.

Comment: I added some details can you help me in decyphring them?

Comment: I would expect the numbers for PX to either be 0 or much higher.  This implies that a parallel DML started but was instantly blocked.  Check if your session is blocked: `select v$session.blocking_session, v$session.* from v$session;`
Or (less likely) your session is waiting for some more resources, like space: `select * from dba_resumable;`